# swift UITableView/ UICollectionView call observe(\.xxx) didn't work

Tags: ios, swift

```
collection.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UICollectionView.contentSize), options: .new, context: nil)

 collection.observe(\.contentSize) { (collection, change) in
         
  }
```

when I use "addObserver" to observe contentSize, it's worked,
but observe(.contentSize) is not work, I don't know why.

Comment: Is the backslash intentional? That could cause a compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare with the example here:

```
class MyObserver: NSObject {
    @objc var objectToObserve: MyObjectToObserve
    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    init(object: MyObjectToObserve) {
        objectToObserve = object
        super.init()
        
        observation = observe(
            \.objectToObserve.myDate,
            options: [.old, .new]
        ) { object, change in
            print("myDate changed from: \(change.oldValue!), updated to: \(change.newValue!)")
        }
    }
}
```

The observe method returns an "observation" token, and you need to hang on to it. It stops observing if/when it goes out of scope.